# SQL: Check if a column contains any of given values

Tags: sql

Need your help with SQL. I've following table:

```
USERID  RuleID
1        101 
1        102
1        103 
2        101 
2        103
3        101
3        102
```

I would like to get all userIDs where RuleID 102 exists, but doesn't have both Rule 101 and 103. e.g. in the above sample it should return me UserID 3..

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I dont understand. UserId 3 has RuleID 101, isnt it? How come 3 be your output if your condition is "get all userIDs where RuleID 102 exists, but doesn't have either Rule 101 or 103"

Comment: @evil333 Maybe he means _both_ 101 and 103?

Comment: @evil333. yes I meant if it doesn't have both 101 and 103. Thanks Tim..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return userid's that only have 102 and nothing else

```
select userid
from mytable
group by userid
having count(case when ruleid <> 102 then 1 end) = 0
```

If you only want rows that have 102 but don't have both 101 and 103

```
SELECT USERID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY USERID
HAVING
(
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RuleID = 101 THEN 1 END) = 0 OR
    COUNT(CASE WHEN RuleID = 103 THEN 1 END) = 0
) 
    AND COUNT(CASE WHEN RuleID = 102 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Here is a link with a running demo for the second query:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca8c58/10)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid
FROM sometable
WHERE RuleID = 101 
AND userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM sometable WHERE RuleID IN (102, 103))
```